# How to authenticate to GogoleApis using Node.js on a lambda function

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-sheets, aws-lambda, google-api

I'm trying to access a Google sheet from an AWS Lambda function.
When testing the code locally it works fine, but when I deploy it to the function I get an error message saying it can't find the credentials.json file.

Error:

```
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/google-credentials.json'",
  "trace": [
    "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/google-credentials.json'"
  ]
}
```

Here is an example code of how I'm trying to authenticate:

```
// index.ts
import { google } from "googleapis";
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
        keyFile: "./google-credentials.json",
        scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    });
const googleClient = await auth.getClient();
// create instance of google sheets API
const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth: googleClient });
const spreadsheetId = process.env.SPREADSHEET_ID;
// const locationRange = "Locations!A4:H161";
const ranges = ["Locations!A4:H161", "2022-2023 Campus!A1:M116"];

try {
    // Fetch the spreadsheet data
    const spreadsheetData = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchGet({
        auth,
        spreadsheetId,
        ranges,
    });
}
```

From what I understand, the lambda is having a problem finding the google-credentials.json file on line 3 of the code `keyFile: "./google-credentials.json"`
the file is on the root folder, but on the error it says /var/task/ folder.

Any Ideas on what is happening?
Do I need to give some kind of access to the file?
Maybe change how I'm trying to authenticate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the `google-credentials.json` file was not uploaded to AWS.

I'm using [aws-lambda-build](https://github.com/Max-Kolodezniy/aws-lambda-build) npm package to deploy the function.
While generating the js file from typescript, the credentials file was not included in the build.

To fix it, I just had to create a build, add the index.js and the credentials.json file to a zip and deploy using the zip option.
That way both files are include.

The way I got around it, and continued to use the `lambda-build` to deploy the project was to import the file as a module inside `index.ts`

```
 import googleCredentials from "./google-credentials.json";
```

And insteadof using the `keyfile:` inside `auth`, I changed it to `credentials`

```
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    credentials: googleCredentials,
    scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
});
```

Also had to add `"resolveJsonModule": true,` to the compiler options inside `tsconfig.json` so the compiler includes the file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In orther to access files packaged with your function code, you should use the `LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT` reserved environment variable. You could do something like:

```js
keyFile: `${process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/google-credentials.json`
```

References:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html

Answer (score 0):

Another option:
Store your credentials in environment variables (should secured env vars),
and create json object from those values.

You can access env vars:

```
process.env.YOURCUSTONVARIABLENAME
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html

Env variables stores key-value pairs where the value can be a string.
Maybe you should store the credentials as a string and create a JSON object from that in lambda.
Or store only the json object's sensitive parts separately and generate the credentials object on the fly.

As you did, you can use credentials and not keyfile, like [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/issues/1456#issuecomment-1240270318)

Comment: Can I store a JSON object as a value? Would that be a problem since the API is looking for a .json file? On the google auth, I think I can substitute the `keyFile:`, for `credentials:` according to the docs. So I can just pass a JSON object instead of the file.